# Google Sheets Price Tracker for Amazon not functioning properly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Hi so i'm using a slightly edited version of a price tracker made by someone else. The purpose of this tracker is to track the price of certain items on Amazon and then display them without me having to check each price individually.

The problem however, is that the tracker is only returning the price of about 20 different items even though I have asked it to track more.

If anyone can take a look at the code and tell me what is causing it to "give up" after it has displayed about 20 items that would be amazing, I have had a look myself but i'm fairly new in the world of coding and I really don't know what the problem is.

If you can tell me how to fix the problem too that would be really helpful.

Main Script:
http://pastebin.com/4zfiZjnU

Table Script:
http://pastebin.com/sWSCM8w4

Row Script:
com/nWLzRNV5

Answer (score 0):

Try changing function function trackPrices(). The line 'data  = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 21, 3).getValues();' is only getting 20 rows (it skips the header row. Try changing 21 to your number of rows you have +1 and see if that works.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, I have tried what you suggested... It hasn't really fixed the problem. The tracker seems to be skipping many of the links when it is run (each time it skips out different links) here is a screenshot of the problem : https://gyazo.com/170e113c745c88bc746df65ff0a50836

Comment: You are getting a return code that is not 200 on the blank lines. Try
adding Logger.log(e.toString()); to the catch (e) after the loop where
you changed the 21. This should show you the error. Or use Developer Tools to check the retutn code. You could also try Utilities.Sleep(2000) in the loop to pause between calls to the next url. Or step through the trackprices function in debug.